# How to handle the message-only window to get the messages from the console window?

Tags: winapi, console, windows-console

I'm trying to know when a console window has moved so I created a new message-only window to get the messages of the console but I don't know if it is working because the message is apparently never being received.

```
#define WINVER 0x0501
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

WNDPROC glpfnConsoleWindow; // NEW
using namespace std;

LRESULT APIENTRY MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_SIZE:
        cout<<"Window moved"<<endl;
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
        // NEW
        return CallWindowProc(glpfnConsoleWindow, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        //return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;
    const char lpcszClassName[] = "messageClass";
    WNDCLASSEX  WindowClassEx;

    // == NEW
    HWND consHwnd;
    consHwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    glpfnConsoleWindow = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLong(consHwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)MainWndProc);
    // ==

    ZeroMemory(&WindowClassEx, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    WindowClassEx.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    WindowClassEx.lpfnWndProc   = MainWndProc;
    WindowClassEx.hInstance     = hInstance;
    WindowClassEx.lpszClassName = lpcszClassName;

    if (RegisterClassEx(&WindowClassEx) != 0)
    {
        // Create a message-only window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, lpcszClassName, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
        if (hwnd != NULL)
        cout<<"Window created"<<endl;
        else
        UnregisterClass(lpcszClassName, hInstance);
    }
    ShowWindow(hwnd,nCmdShow);
    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
     return (int)Msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: I have edited the code to add lines related to SetWindowLong (using comment "NEW")

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should process [WM_MOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which, according to the documentation, is sent after the window has been moved. WM_SIZE is sent when the size changes.

I think your problem is that the `WM_MOVE` and `WM_SIZE` messages are going to the console window rather than to your hidden window.

I suspect you'll have to call [GetConsoleWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the console window handle, and then call [SetWindowLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to attach your window proc to the console window. Be sure to pass messages on to the original window proc.

Comment: But it has been also tested maximixing/minimizing the window

Comment: I get "SetWindowLongAccess is denied".

Comment: @user2397585: Edit your question to show what you've tried, and explain what error you're getting.

Comment: @user2397585: Again, we can provide no help without an example.